# Excel report with increasing list of rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to build a report which lists products in column A and qty sold / revenue / units on hand in the next 3 columns. Something like this:

```
Products  Qty Sold  Revenue  Units on Hand
--------  --------  -------  -------------
A         1         10       3
B         2         20       4
C         1         20       5
D         3         30       6
```

Ideally, i want to setup this report in a way that I can dump data in a data tab and have it populate here. I can easily set that up with a sumifs formula.

The problem i'm facing is: How do i deal with an expanding list of products in column A?

For example, next week there is a new product 'E' that has some sales and i need to be able to dynamically add it in. It'll be tough for me to add it in manually as, in the real report, there will be hundreds of products listed. I could setup a pivot table but i'm not comfortable doing that with the audience i'll be sharing the report with.

Let me know if this makes sense and if i need to provide any additional information to clarify this problem.

Thanks for your help, appreciate it!

Comment: How often will you import new data into the `data` tab?  If it isn't too often, then you could create a pivot table of the product names from the newly imported data, and then copy/paste-values to `Column A` on your report tab, and then copy your formulas down to the new rows that don't yet have formulas...  Then you could simply delete the pivot table tab.  If you want it all automated, there are VBA formulas to create a unique list of items.  But your spreadsheet would then have macro code, and that would complicate distribution to others...

Comment: Data would need to be imported weekly. And yes, the pivot solution is the solution i was thinking of too but again that's a 2 step process. Basically, i wont be the guy pulling in data every week, so i want to make it as easy as possible for the person who will be doing it weekly

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a pivot table, I'd say your best bet is to write a short macro to make sure every product on your data tab shows up in your report tag. For example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CheckDataAndAddToReport()
Dim wsReport As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
Dim startRow As Long, endRow As Long, currRow As Long, addRow As Long
Dim missingCt As Long

Set wsReport = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report") 'put the name of your Report sheet here
Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data") 'put the name of your Data sheet here

'startRow will be the first row with data in the data worksheet
startRow = 2

'set endRow to the last row with data in the data worksheet
endRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'loop through all the rows of the data worksheet with data
For currRow = startRow To endRow

    'check to see if the item on the current row is found in the reports page
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsReport.Columns(1), wsData.Cells(currRow, 1).Value) = 0 Then

        'if not, add it and the relevant formulas
        addRow = wsReport.Cells(wsReport.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wsReport.Cells(addRow, 1).Formula = wsData.Cells(currRow, 1).Value
        wsReport.Cells(addRow, 2).Formula = "" 'put whatever formulas you need to here
        wsReport.Cells(addRow, 3).Formula = "" 'put whatever formulas you need to here
        wsReport.Cells(addRow, 4).Formula = "" 'put whatever formulas you need to here

        'keep a count of how many were added for reporting purposes
        missingCt = missingCt + 1

    End If

Next currRow

'show a message box with the results
If missingCt > 0 Then
    MsgBox "A total of " & missingCt & " items were found in " & wsData.Name & " that were missing from " & wsReport.Name & " and were added.", _
    vbInformation, _
    "Results"
Else
    MsgBox "No items were found to be missing from " & wsReport.Name & ".", _
    vbInformation, _
    "Results"
End If

End Sub
```